# RxJS operator bufferTime

Tags: rxjs

Why does the code

```
interval(1000)
    .pipe(
        take(15),
        bufferTime(5000)
    )
    .subscribe(sequence => {
        console.log(sequence);
    });
```

generates

```
[ 0, 1, 2, 3 ]
[ 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 ]
[ 9, 10, 11, 12, 13 ]
[ 14 ]
```

Why the first batch only has 4 items?

Comment: You're querying by time. I'd suggest you're getting a race condition.

Comment: Because the `bufferTime` implementation is subscribed to first and that operator's implementation calls `setInterval` _before_ the implementation of `interval` calls `setInterval` within its implementation - so the buffer closes first.

Answer (score 1):

This is because `interval(1000)` will wait initially 1s to emit hence for the first batch the 4 values only. If you want to "fix" this and have 5 in the first batch, use `timer(0, 1000)` which will do the same as your `interval(1000)` except that it'll start straight away instead of waiting 1s.

Answer (score -1):

In this case it's probably because `interval` doesn't emit immediately, so when 5000ms have elapsed, it's possible that only 4 emissions have happened.

I say possible because due to how intervals and timeouts work in JS, there aren't any guarantees of the kind that would assure us of exactly 5 emissions per buffer in your example. Callbacks that are scheduled in a specific amount are only guaranteed to be called sometime after the timeout elapses, not exactly when the duration ends.

There's a decent chance you could see a group of 6 if you run it enough (since 1000 divides so evenly into 5000, even a millisecond of variance would push it over the edge). Using 100ms and 500ms might illustrate it more clearly more quickly, but the principle holds.

Comment: "There's a decent chance you could see a group of 6 if you run it enough" - I'd expect that to be impossible. That would require a further second of collecting extra values, not a millisecond. It's the millisecond that's giving 4, rather than 5.

Comment: Sorry, but that's not correct. The minimum amount of time required to sample 6 values from a 1000ms interval is 5001 milliseconds. Pretend there's 999 dots between each emit: `x....x....x....x....x.....x`. So it does require just a millisecond of collecting extra values, which is very possible.

Comment: Unless `Interval` is implemented differently in RxJS, it doesn't emit an element until the first interval has passed.

Comment: Here's the comment from the RxJS source - `The first emission is not sent immediately, but only after the first period has passed.`

Comment: Sure, but it keeps running, right? I'm not saying you'll see a six first, just eventually. My point was the unreliability of timers in general.

Comment: But you won't get 6 unless there's a massive issue with the timing. It's virtually impossible. It's certainly not a "decent chance".

Comment: I can reproduce it by adding 0-10ms of random noise to the timers. Is that sort of event loop delay really that inconceivable?

Comment: 1 full second is pretty much inconceivable.